# I cannot launch static video file served by express from HTML

Tags: html, node.js, windows

I try to make an HTML page with a video. I launch my application on windows 7. All application operates as expected except media. The media file layouts in the 'public' folder in my project. But it doesn't play. The browser console gives the error: "GET http://localhost:8000/1.webm 404 (Not Found)". How can I launch the video in my application?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="public/1.webm" controls>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var app = express();
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.listen(8000);
console.log("Server has started!");
```

Comment: Can you run the server and go to `http://localhost:8000/public/1.webm ` and tell us if the video is present?

Comment: @Y4glory, no video . Error is:Cannot GET /1.webm

Comment: So are there any other assets in your public directory?

Comment: @Y4glory, no, but  I tried to put the file in the root of the project next to index.js, but the file did not play. The problem isn't layout public folder.

Comment: You can't just put it in the index and expect it to serve it like apache, it's an express server. You need to configure it to serve all the files. Thats why you have the line which says `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`

Comment: @Y4glory, Is it problem with 'public' folder? How can I decide it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211236/discussion-between--and-y4glory).